# Understanding Logic Using Iteration for Master/Slave

Tags: c

I took over a project from unknown predecessor who had gone without proper documents and comments.
Now I am trying to analyze his codes, but it is hard to follow up.

Basically, there are **32 channels** hook up with a micro controller. What he seems like trying to do is find **slave channels** between 32 channels once those information is sent from a server.

1. call nextslave()

   for (scan=0 ; (scan = nextslave(chan, scan)) != -1 ; scan++)
2. nextslave() looks like below

/**
 * nextslave - gets the channel number of the next slave channel
 *    associated with the master. returns -1 if no more slaves.
 *    channel and start are zero-based. 
 */

```
short nextslave(short channel, short start)
{
    short    mask, major, minor;
    unsigned char    *p;

/* fix-up the slaveflag[] index values */
major = start / 8;
minor = start % 8;

/* init a pointer into the slaveflag[] array */
p = &(chparam[channel].slaveflag[major]);

/* now let us find the next slave channel (if any) */
for (; major < (NUMCHANS / 8) ; major++, p++)
{
    minor &= 0x07;
    for (mask = (0x01 << minor) ; minor < 8 ; mask <<= 1, minor++)
    {
        if (*p & mask)
        {
            /* found one so calculate channel# and return */
            return ((major * 8) + minor);
        }
    }
}
/* if we reach here then there are no (more) slaves */
return (-1);
}
```

What I have analyzed so far is:

1. start variable keeps iterating until 32 in nextslave().
2. when the start var is 0~7, major var is 0 and minor var changes from 0 to 7,also mask var changes 1,2,4,8,16...
3. When the start var is 8 ~15, major var is 1, and minor var still keep changing from 0 to 7
4. Keep iterating until major var becomes 4.(I don't know the meaning of major var in his codes)
5. In second for loop, return something if *p(pointer to values from server) & mask is true

I am not clear about general idea about what he intended to for this process. Especially, in the second for loop, if there is no match up in `if(*p&mask)`, then go back to the first for loop. However, **minor variable was being increased without clearing out like 0**. So once the code hits `minor &= 0x07`, the processor will do bitwise with the last value of minor although major var keeps increasing.

For instance, the range of **minor var is 0 to 7** and there is no match up value, so ends up becoming **7** in the second for loop. **Get out of the loop and go back to the first loop and increases major var by 1**. But **minor var is still 7**, so the second loop will start like `mask =(0x01<<minor)` with **minor =7**.

I feel like need to reset minor =0 whenever getting out the second for loop, but I don't know what he was aiming for. He just wrote down **"master/slave technique"**.

My Questions are:

1. Is it correct with my analysis?
2. How the master/slave technique is used for 32 channels getting ADC?
3. Is the reset code for minor var required? whenever getting out the second for loop.

If you have any idea, please answer anything that helps me out to understand his codes.

Thanks,
Jin

Comment: StackOverflow is a Question and Answer site.   I do not feel you have asked a question.

Comment: If you think the codes are very easy, explain codes for me rather than criticizing my C abilities

Comment: `if(*p&mask), then go back to the first for loop.` Wrong: once a set bit is found we return from the function. `But minor var is still 7, so the second loop will start like mask =(0x01<<minor) with minor =7` wrong again. **after** the second loop, minor will be 8 (the loop condition. But the next time the second loop is entered, (wih an incremented value for major) `minor &= 7;` will restart minor at 0. (and the bitmask will start at `1<<0` (1) again)

Comment: Thanks, `there is no match up in if(*p&mask)` then go back to first loop --> It's right. I missed to say `at the end of loop`. The second your correction is right. minor becomes 8 and masking out to zero.

Comment: No, if the `if (*p & mask)` is not true, the *inner* loop just continues stepping minor and shifting the mask left, Until `minor==8` :then it falls out of the inner loop, and the outer loop can try to bump major.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I meant. I should have said that at the end of `loops`

Comment: Now, is there any question left unanswered?